# Embed URL clickable links in TeamCity build log

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm trying to embed clickable links in my TeamCity logs. 
My custom log message displayed with logging message with the ##teamacity template ([documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity)):

```
log("##teamcity[buildProblem description='message to log to TC']");
```

Now, i want part of the message to be a clickable link, for example, for a screenshot i have taken during the test.

How can it be done?
I'm trying the approach described [here](http://atombrenner.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/embed-url-links-in-teamcity-build-logs.html), which suggesting installing [StaticUIExtensions plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/StaticUIExtensions) to TeamCity and adding a rule that will transform log message the looks like `url(http://www.autoscout24.de)` into a clickable link in the log. It didn't worked for me.

My TeamCity version isEnterprise 8.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I have modified show-link.html script. It works with TC 2017.2.4. And now script looks for "http://" strings instead of "(url)"

**show-link.html**

```html
<script>
  (function ($) {
    function createLinksFromUrls() {
      $("div .fullStacktrace").each(function () {
        var oldHtml = $(this).html();
  if(oldHtml.indexOf("<a href=") < 0)
  {
   var newHtml=oldHtml.replace(/http(.*)/, "<a href='http$1' target='_blank'>htpp$1</a>");
   $(this).html(newHtml);
  }
      });
    }
 
    $(document).ready(createLinksFromUrls);
    $(document).click(function () {
        window.setTimeout(createLinksFromUrls, 50);
        window.setTimeout(createLinksFromUrls, 100);
        window.setTimeout(createLinksFromUrls, 500);
    });
})(window.jQuery); 
</script>
```

**static-ui-extensions.xml**

```html
  <rule place-id="BUILD_RESULTS_FRAGMENT" html-file="show-link.html" >
    <url starts="viewLog.html" />
  </rule>
  <rule place-id="TEST_DETAILS_BLOCK" html-file="show-link.html" >
    <url starts="viewLog.html" />
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The showlinks.html needs an adjustment. Replace BEFORE_CONTENT with BUILD_RESULTS_FRAGMENT and it will work. The file showlinks.html needs to be placed in the same directory where "beforeContent.html" is located (TeamCity/config/_static_ui_extensions).

Comment: that was a good catch. Can you share your entire static-ui-extensions.xml ? I'm trying this same approach but it is not working after making place-id=BUILD_RESULTS_FRAGMENT.